# Generate all changes of signs

Tags: haskell, transform, combinations

I have many lists. Say for short `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. 
I need to generate all changes of signs of each element. Thus, for the short example, the result would be

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[-1,2],[1,-2],[-1,-2],[-3,4],[3,-4],[-3,-4]]
```

Is there a package to perform such an operation ? Otherwise what algorithm could I use ? (I confess I have not thought a lot about it ...).

It this can help, all my lists have the same length.

## Edit

Hmm.. maybe an idea like that:

```
x = [[2*i,2*j] | i <- [1, -1], j <- [-1,1]]
x
[[2,-2],[2,2],[-2,-2],[-2,2]]
```

Comment: It seems like [1, -2] and [3, -4] are missing in your example

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? It is furthermore not really clear to me why the output has type `[[n]]`, instead of `[[[n]]]`.

Comment: Are the sublists always of length 2?

Comment: You are right @Axnyff, they are missing.

Comment: This looks like two operations at once: 1) Generate all possible sign variations for a single list. 2) Apply the operation from #1 to a list of inputs and collect the results. Operation #2 is `map` / `concatMap`.

Comment: @Alex no, the lists are of length 4 usually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem can be broken down to 2 steps:

1. For a given list of numbers, generate all the possible signs
2. For the list of lists, apply the function from (1) to each list, then concat the results.

For 1. you can write a simple recursive function that first processes the tail of the list, then for each resulting combination, it generates two versions for the two signs.

```
signs :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
signs [] = [[]]
signs (x : xs)
  = let ps = signs xs
    in map (x :) ps ++ map ((-x) :) ps
```

For 2. simply map the `signs` function over the input, and concat them. This is what the `concatMap` function does:

```
signsAll :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
signsAll = concatMap signs
```

Comment: Looks good. Thanks a lot. I will test on my real case and surely upvote and accept later.

Comment: `signs = mapM (\x -> [x,-x])`

Comment: There's one issue with your code Csongor: the case of 0. `signsAll [[0,2],[2,3]]
[[0,2],[0,-2],[0,2],[0,-2],[2,3],[2,-3],[-2,3],[-2,-3]]`. You see the duplicates ? I'm too tired this evening to fix that.

Comment: @DanielWagner there's the zero issue.

Comment: @גלעדברקן No problem, `signs = mapM (\x -> nub [x,-x])`.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to use an applicative here, because it looks like you are almost there

```
[id,negate] <*> [3,4]
```

but it turned out that I need `sequence` and `map`, which, in this case, can be combined into a `traverse`:

```
traverse (\x->[x,-x]) [3,4]
[[3,4],[3,-4],[-3,4],[-3,-4]]
```

As others mentioned, now you need `concatMap` for your function:

```
concatMap (traverse (\x->[x,-x])) [[3,4],[1,2]]
[[3,4],[3,-4],[-3,4],[-3,-4],[1,2],[1,-2],[-1,2],[-1,-2]]
```